# Bottom Level Graphics Programming/ Working with Screen Hardware

Tags: c, assembly, screen, driver, hardware

It is said that a 'low level' programming language is one that works 'close' to the hardware. I work with C as well as Python and Java and it is generally excepted that C is a 'lower level' language or works 'closer' to the hardware than these other two languages. This of course makes sense because python and java are C derived  languages.

So what I want to know is what is the 'lowest level' or 'closest to hardware' way of working with the computer screen to display pixel graphics on a monitor?

Basically, how does the screen work on the programming 'back end'?

Just to be perfectly clear I'll give an analogy. When I first learned about python lists, I figured they were multiple numbers stored together. What I later learned was that they are actually pointers to locations in memory reserved for the length of the array in units of the data type.

So what I know about the screen is that its a grid of pixels x wide, y long. When you refer to this grid with functions that accept some form of vector, a pixel will light up a specified colour at that pixel's coordinance (0,0 starts top left of course.) What is *really* going on in those functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

s[Machine code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_code) is lowest you can go.  And this even still gets interpreted by the CPU. (Dependent on CPU of course)

Generally most people will go only as low as [assembler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assembly_language#Assembler) though.

(I didn't mention GPU programming as you mentioned Python, Java, C and made an assumption you are trying to get to grips with the old way of rendering).

**EDIT**

Missed your other question

Pointers are used when a block of memory needs referencing.  Simple data types do not require a pointer (but can still have one).  This is dependent on the language and how it allows data type allocation.

In the case of a list/array of data you can not allocate this on the heap as it is a varying length so a block of memory is request from the operating system which will return a pointer to this section of memory that can be used.  The operating system does not care how this is used and it's up to the application to know how much to allocate and how it should use it.

This is why languages use data types so the compiler knows how to manipulate that block of memory.  Now nothing stops you manipulating this block of memory directly but you must follow the rules the compile uses since any further code executed could cause errors.

**EDIT**

Additional based on comment.

When modifying a a buffer that if linked to hardware you need to understand the specs for the buffer.  Usually you have already requested the device to use a certain MODE of operation and you know how the hardware will behave.  This is why varying standards arose to help programmer use these.  I am going to reference to a very good old school programming guide for hardware it should help you a lot [PC Game Programmer's Encyclopedia](http://bespin.org/~qz/pc-gpe/)

These concepts still apply to operating systems now in windows you would use the GDI to allocate these screens and the GDI interfaces to a driver to present the required image.  The guide I linked is about using hardware directly from old operating systems which have no graphics support (MS-DOS for example)

Comment: I'm more interested in how it works than actually doing it. How are pixels arranged in memory? How does the cpu communicate with the screen hardware?

Comment: I'll read about assembler but I'm not at this point in my skill willing do drop lower than C, if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

The word you are looking for is frame buffer. For an introduction see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Framebuffer

Comment: mmm looks like the right link. Seems like the short answer is that it is exactly the same as lists.

Comment: Do you know where I can find instructions on how to work directly with the frame buffer in C. It's a pity the book I read never covered this stuff.

Comment: There is a project http://www.microwindows.org which covers programming of various types of framebuffers. This project is primarily aimed at platforms other than PC, as you would be hard pressed for a reason to not use the library functions. fblinXX.c in the microwindows project describe various ways of accessing frame buffer.

Comment: You can see the layout possibilities for a PXA-270 processor in developers manual at http://www.marvell.com/application-processors/pxa-family/assets/pxa_27x_dev_man.pdf